# Will a Windows server 2003 operate on a domain functional level 2012 domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2

I have found plenty of articles that address Server 2012 R2 on a functional level 2003 domain. What I haven't been able to find is anyone addressing weather or not a 2003 server would be fully operational in a 2012 functional level domain. Can anyone confirm that it would work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple 2003 member server will have no problems working in a 2012 (or 2012 R2 for that matter) functional level domain.  But you won't be able to have a 2003 server running as a DC.

Comment: Yep, it'll run just fine as a server, but it cannot be a domain controller(or probably much else).